# What is the value of $\text{arg}(z) + \text{arg}(\bar{z})$ for a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the value of $\text{arg}(z) + \text{arg}(\bar{z})$ for a complex number?

According to me the answer should be $0$, by basic $\tan^{-1}$ logic and also since $$arg(z) + \text{arg}(\bar{z}) = \text{arg}(z\bar{z}) = \text{arg}(x^2 + y^2) = 0$$

> Considering that $z = x + iy$, therefore I wanted to clarify that is it always $0$ or can it be $2\pi$ aswell? If so in which case and how?

Comment: Depends on your interval of "principal values of arguments".

Comment: $\arg(z)$ is a multi-valued function, you have to specify first which value is chosen.

Comment: @xbh oh now I understand why there was an option of "Can't say" since the question would be baseless without mentioning the principal argument.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of a complex number is only defined modulo $2\pi$ so the arguments $0$ and $2\pi$ are essentially the same.

Sometimes texts use the convention that arguments must be in the interval $[0,2\pi)$. In that case $2\pi$ is not the argument.

Comment: @user Fixed thanks. You could have made the edit.